# Help understanding why the image in part B does not diverge, yet the one in part C does

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

[Screenshot of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEZE.jpg)

I understand the first one because for the given point in the center, the vectors are all pointing away. But part B and part C look almost entirely similar to me. Could someone help me understand why the image in part B is not divergent yet the image in part C ***is divergent***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field in part B is *constant*, so certainly has divergence $0$. Because the length of the vector field in part C increases as you move upwards, you will get positive flux across a rectangle with its sides parallel to the axes (more flows out across the top than flows in across the bottom).